# Spring boot + Oauth 2.0 + BCryptPasswordEncoder hashing issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, password-encryption

I have set `passwordEncoder` as `BCryptPasswordEncoder` while configuring OAuth2.0 in spring boot which working fine except OAuth when internally encodes password for comparison it pre-fixes hash with `{bcrypt}` and hence `bCryptPasswordEnoder.matches` returns false. can anyone help me with unintended prefix of `{bcrypt}`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spring-security-5 uses `DeligatingPasswordEncoder` which recognizes what type was used to create particular hash using prefix e.g. `{bcrypt}` and under the hood chooses correct algorithm for authentication e.g. BCrypt ot SCrypt. [Refer to this for more info](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-password-storage)